# Select query returning only 1 of 2 requested columns

Tags: php, sql

I'm 90% sure the problem is in the sql syntax, but can't seem to spot where exactly. The sql is returning the correct email, however the password returns empty. I have tried using a different column in the database but I get the same problem.

Note: The password is hashed in db.

Code:

```
$sql = $link->prepare('SELECT email, password FROM users WHERE email=:email');
$sql->bindParam(':email', $email);
$sql->execute();
$resultemail = $sql->fetchColumn();
$resultpassword = $sql->fetchColumn(1);
if (!$resultemail){
    echo "empty";
} else {
    echo $resultemail;
}
if (!$resultpassword){
    echo "empty";
} else {
    echo "$resultpassword";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each time you call `fetchColumn`, it moves to the next row of the result set, and fetches the specified column from that row (the default is column 0). So you're setting `$resultemail` to the first column of the first row of the results, and `$resultpassword` to the first column of the second row of the results. But since the query only returns one row, you're setting `$resultpassword` to `false`.

You should fetch the whole row, and set the variables to the corresponding columns of that row.

```
$row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if ($row) {
    $resultemail = $row['email'];
    $resultpassword = $row['password'];
    if (!$resultemail){
        echo "empty";
    } else {
        echo $resultemail;
    }
    if (!$resultpassword){
        echo "empty";
    } else {
        echo "$resultpassword";
    }
} else {
    echo "empty";
}
```

Comment: I'm getting this error message now. Call to undefined method PDOStatement::fetchAssoc().

Comment: Got it, just replaced fetchAssoc() with fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC). So.. novice question. The difference between the two methods is that fetchAssoc() is procedural and fetch() is oop?

Comment: Yeah, sorry. It's hard to keep all the different APIs straight.

Comment: Haha second problem you fixed for me today, I appreciate your help